# Signature verification failed when installing MySQL 5.7.29 on Suse Linux Leap 15.1

Tags: mysql

I want to install MySQL community edition 5.7.29 on **OpenSuse Linux leap 15.1** as following:

1. Download the file: mysql-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar;
2. untar the file then get 8 files

   ```
   >mysql-community-client-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-common-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-devel-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-embedded-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-embedded-devel-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-libs-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-server-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm

   >mysql-community-test-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm
   ```
3. install the 4 files rpm using the command:

   ```
   >sudo zypper install mysql-community-{server,client,common,libs}-*
   ```
4. Then the error message shows as below:

   ```
   >mysql-community-common-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64.rpm:
   Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
   V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY

   >Looking for gpg key ID 5072E1F5 in cache /var/cache/zypp/pubkeys.
   Repository Plain RPM files cache does not define additional 
   'gpgkey=' URLs.
   mysql-community-common-5.7.29-1.sles12.x86_64 (Plain RPM files 
   cache): Signature verification failed [4-Signatures public key is 
   not available]

   >Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a):
   ```

Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write `i` to bypass this issue and successfully complete installation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue because by default OpenSUSE use downloads.opensuse.org repository that seems to use proxy to nearest server mirror, but the problem is that it seems some mirrors does not update something on his servers so you found messages like "Signature verification failed".
You can try several solutions:

1. Use some VPN service to change your IP location to find a chance that download.opensuse.org will redirect you on some good mirror.
2. Change "download.opensuse.org" domain in the repo configuration in the /etc/repo.d (or /etc/zypp/repo.d) to some other server from the list: https://mirrors.opensuse.org/list/15.0.html and put it into the repository files (/etc/repo.d/* or /etc/zypp/*), e.g. http://nrt.edge.kernel.org/opensuse (instead of http://download.opensuse.org).

Also you can change source server even in the OpenSUSE installation mode while use graphical install. For that you should cancel graphical install and when text mode menu opened, in the "Expert mode" you can edit configuration from the console. In the console you can't use "vi" so use "sed" command to change the file contents.

Scan configs:

```
grep "downloads.opensuse.org" -r /etc
```

Change content for every file:

```
sed -i s/downloads.opensuse.org/nrt.edge.kernel.org\/opensuse/g /etc/products.d/openSUSE.prod
...
```